# What does the symbol $\Delta$ imply? Standard deviation or variance?

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, sampling, standard-deviation, mean

I know that $\left<x\right>$ is 80. But when it is written that $\Delta x/\left<x\right> = 0.2$, I don't know immediately how to do a sampling of $x$, since standard deviation is mostly written in $\sigma$ but not $\Delta$.

Does this mean that the distribution of $x$ is a normal distribution? Also does it imply the standard deviation being 16 or the variance being 16?

(The only word description is that the distribution of $x$ is sufficiently peaked at 80)

Comment: Why only those two rather than say mean deviation? I've seen $\Delta$ used for that before.

Comment: (1) Where have you seen those symbols? Please provide some reference since neither of those is commonly used. The symbols should be defined in your source. (2) [$\Delta$ is commonly used to denote "change"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_(letter)), I haven't seen it used for SD or variance. (3) The fact that you can compute mean and sd for some variable does not imply anything about it's distribution...

Comment: Also, full width at half maximum http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FullWidthatHalfMaximum.html is another way to summarize spread.

Comment: it does use to denote standard deviation in physics http://web.mit.edu/~emin/www.old/writings/quantum/img37.gif  , but this is not sampling though (although i am reading a physics article)

Comment: @Nick Cox is fwhm the same as standard deviation?

Comment: @kyle Not in general. This thread can at best be speculative unless and until you show a source we can understand to explain.

Answer (score 1):

Δ is usually used to denote a change. Is it possible that this denotes a percentage of change of x compared to either the new or the old x? Can you edit your question to give more information about the specific situation?

Comment: I think this is a good guess but from the formula given the quantity might be fractional change, but not percent.

Comment: Yes, you are of course totally right, my mistake! Wrong word choice

Comment: i found that it may mean indeed follow a normal distribution. if it is normal distribution, and the $\Delta$ means change, does it mean that standard deviation or variance? This should also be always positive.